# Getting syslog-ng json output as sensu standalone event

Tags: json, syslog-ng, sensu

Could one please advise best way to convert syslog-ng event in json (like http://hastebin.com/gesuyuluwo.json ) in [sensu](http://sensuapp.org) as (critical) event?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know sennsu, but in syslog-ng OSE 3.5 you can convert log messages to JSON format:http://www.balabit.com/sites/default/files/documents/syslog-ng-ose-3.5-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-v3.5-guide-admin/html/reference-template-functions.html#template-function-format-json

HTH

Robert